# combination of \r \t in pythong string breaks python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

What's happening here?

```
In [1]: q = 'deadbeef\t1.2.3.4\t2019-07-04\r",2019-07-02\r\n' 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: print(q)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
",2019-07-02    1.2.3.4 2019-07-04


In [3]:
```

Why is print inverting the order of the substrings? I've tested it on python 2.7, 3.6, 3.7

Comment: There’s an `\r`. `\r` (without `\n`) goes back to the start of the line and writes over it.

Comment: At first i was like, how can someone break python `:0`. After reading the explaination, i'm like `__|_` .

Comment: Use raw string to print it without any error. `q = r'deadbeef\t1.2.3.4\t2019-07-04\r",2019-07-02\r\n'`. Or, use `repr(q)` instead.